# Автоматическая отправка сообщений в WhatsApp Web

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, websocket, whatsapp

**Добрый день, уважаемые пользователи!**

Я задался одним интересным вопросом относительно ***рассылки в WhatsApp Web без использования бизнес аккаунта***.

Понимаю, что **это очень рискованный шаг**, так как можно схватить блокировку, но эта рассылка нужна на маленький круг лиц (внутри нашей организации) и пользователи не будут жаловаться на нее, а в нынешнее время не представляется возможным создать бизнес аккаунт, так как для этого нужно, чтобы корректно работал Facebook.

Разрабатываю приложение я на платформе .NET Framework 4.8 (c#, VisualStudio 2022).
Я начинаю потихоньку разбираться, нашел возможность сформировать строку типа:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + phoneNumber + "&text=" + messageToSend);
```

После этого происходит открытие страницы WhatsApp Web, далее открывается диалог с нужным пользователем и в поле сообщения вставляется текст.

Однако я не могу понять как мне автоматизировать отправку сообщения. Я хотел бы уйти от использования костылей типа:

1. Отправить команду `SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");`. Она в целом могла бы решить проблему, но зачастую при открытии чата и вставки сообщения курсор не устанавливается в поле ввода сообщения, поэтому это нажатие не отрабатывает, а точнее срабатывает впустую.
2. Писать метод для поиска кнопки отправки сообщения на странице WhastApp Web, вычислять ее координаты и далее вызывать метод нажатия ЛКМ. Это решение также будет работать, но оно не совсем надежное, так как могут возникать ошибки, в том числе возникающие по вине пользователя.

Поэтому мне очень хотелось бы узнать:

***Существует ли какой-то способ автоматизировать этот процесс?***

Ведь мы можем открыть WhatsApp Web, открыть чат, вставить сообщение. Остается только инициировать отправку. Возможно требуется сформировать какую-то строку запроса для этого.

Comment: Selenium смотрели?

Comment: Нет. Есть информация куда копать? Был бы крайне благодарен!

Comment: Ну я вам слово для поиска дал, найти инфу по нему элементарно

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду копать. О результате обязательно напишу!